# why "Artists" table and linking table "ArtistAlbums" is not populate

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to achieve many-to-many relationship with a linking table through EF code first approach.

The classes and context class are below,

```
public class Album
{
    public Album()
    {
        Artists = new List<Artist>();
    }
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }

    public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public Artist()
    {
        Albums = new List<Album>();
    }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

 public class ContextClass : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; } 
}
```

While I am trying to add a album with two artists, then data populate only in "album" table, but no data available in other table "artist" and in linking table,please suggest?

```
using (var context = new ContextClass())
        {
            // add an album for two artists
            var artist1 = new Artist { FirstName = "Tobby", LastName = "Keith" };
            var artist2 = new Artist { FirstName = "Merle", LastName = "Haggard" };
            var album = new Album { AlbumName = "Honkytonk University" };
            artist1.Albums.Add(album);
            artist2.Albums.Add(album);
            context.Albums.Add(album);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `album.Artists.Add(artist1);album.Artists.Add(artist2);` instead?

Comment: that's works. wow! but what is the difference??

Comment: When you add the album to the artist, you create the link from Artist -> Album. Then you add the album object to the context. The album object has no links, so EF doesn't do anything. You could also change the code instead to `context.Artists.Add(artist1);context.Artists.Add(artist2);` and EF would see the links and create the album

Comment: your where tinking upside down @user584018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
artist1.Albums.Add(album);
artist2.Albums.Add(album);
```

use

```
album.Artists.Add(artist1);
album.Artists.Add(artist2);
```

The issue is that only the 'album' object has been added to the context. The local 'album' object has no references to the Artist objects, so EF does not create the linked entities.

NOTE:

You could also replace

```
context.Albums.Add(album);
```

with

```
context.Artists.Add(artist1);
context.Artists.Add(artist2);
```

These local objects do have references, so EF will create the linked entity and the linking table entries.